# can i sort stored score in nsuserdefaults?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

i am developing game application ,in that app i am storing name,score in nsuserdefaults ....but
the according to my requirement i want to store name and score (high to low) based on score ....is there any solution for sorting score in nsuserdefaults... i want show my high score on top

thank's in adv

-(void)btnSaveScore
{
      if(!dictWinData)
            dictWinData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

```
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    array = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"ScoreName"] mutableCopy];
    if([array count] == 0)
    {
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strNameOFPlayer];
NSString *strScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",iTap]];

if([strNameOFPlayer length]==7)
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                   %@",strName,strScore]];
else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 6)
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                     %@",strName,strScore]];
else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 5)
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                       %@",strName,strScore]];
else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 4)
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                         %@",strName,strScore]];
else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 3)
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                           %@",strName,strScore]];
else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 2)
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                             %@",strName,strScore]];
else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 1)
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                              %@",strName,strScore]];

   NSUserDefaults *dfltsData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [dfltsData setObject:array forKey:@"ScoreName"];
   [dfltsData synchronize];
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                message:@"Score is saved."
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
          [alert show];
          [alert release];
```

please help me out

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mJGJq3sa plese check my new code ......now also am geting crash on NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [self sortByfloatvalue:scoreCardArray array:playerarray];
         arrScores = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0];
         arrPlayers = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:1];   these lines

Comment: please check link  http://pastebin.com/mJGJq3sa my new code prince today is last day of my project dead line please plzzz??????? refer my mistakes in my code ???? hope ur understood my problem?

Comment: NSMutableArray *sortedArr = [NSMutableArray alloc]init; replace with NSMutableArray *sortedArr = [NSMutableArray array]; in sortByfloatvalue . NSLog sortedArray

Answer (score 1):

Get array from NSUserDefault like this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrScores = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] ObjectforKey:@"ScoreName"];
```

Now sort arrScores should only contain strScore value only using below method:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)sortByfloatvalue:(NSMutableArray *)array
{ 

  for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
  {
    for(int j=i+1;j<[array count];j++)
    {
        if([[array objectAtIndex:i] floatValue] < [[array objectAtIndex:j] floatValue])
        {
            [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j];
        }
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: in sorted array from highest to lowest below it will show top most ten like this : if([soretedArray count]>=10){for(int i=0; i<10;i++){NSLog(@"%@",[soretedArray objectAtIndex:i];}}